# Landau/Lifshitz Particle Disintegration

Tags: classical-mechanics, inertial-frames, conventions, notation

In Landau/Lifshitz "Mechanics", 3e., there is a problem which asks the reader to find the relation between the angles $\theta_1,\theta_2$ in the lab frame when a particle disintegrates into two parts. I can solve the problem, with one exception: L+L claim the two angles in the COM frame satisfy:

$$
\theta_{20}+\theta_{10}=\pi
$$

where subscript 0 refers to the COM frame. I don't see this: by conservation of momentum

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin\theta_{10}&&\sin\theta_{20}\\
\cos\theta_{10}&&\cos\theta_{20}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{10}\\p_{20}
\end{bmatrix}
=0
$$

and this has a solution iff the determinant of the matrix on the LHS vanishes:

$$
\sin(\theta_{20}-\theta_{10})=0
\implies
\theta_{20}-\theta_{10}=\pi
$$

Are L+L just using a different convention to measure $\theta_{10},\theta_{20}$ than I am? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like a convention difference. The physical point is that the particles have to come out back to back. If you understand that then there's no issue.